# Add the attributes of selected features to my new layer in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am trying to create a layer from the selected points coordinates. I am drawing a circle to the coordinate of selected points. I also need to add initial attributes of my selected features to my new layer. I tried some examples but every time I failed. Can anyone help me with this. Need to add something before "provider.addFeatures( [feature] )"

```
def draw_circle_to_selected_coordinates(self):
    """
    Gets the coordinate of selected features and draws the circles for desired radius in qgis
    """

    #set active layer as layer
    layer = utils.iface.activeLayer()
    selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()


    #creating layer structure using selected layer fields.
    fields = layer.pendingFields()
    fields_in="Polygon?"
    field_counter=1

    for field in fields:
        fields_in=fields_in+'field='+str(field.name())+ ':'+str(field.typeName())+'&'
        field_counter+=field_counter


    fields_in= fields_in+('field=Band:Double')


    #creates new memory layer for radial bands with selected layer attributes
    vpoly = QgsVectorLayer(fields_in, "RadialBand", "memory")
    feature = QgsFeature()
    provider = vpoly.dataProvider()
    vpoly.startEditing()

    #get band radiuses from the file
    list=[]
    f=open("radial_band.nodelete", "r")
    with open('radial_band.nodelete') as openfileobject:
        for line in openfileobject:
            value=float(line.strip())
            list.append(value)
    f.close()

    #filling radial band table with selected feature coordinates and desired radiuses
    for f in selected_features:
        geom = f.geometry()
        x=float(geom.asPoint().x())
        y=float(geom.asPoint().y())
        item=0
        for item in range(0, len(list)):
            radius=list[item]
    #draw circle to the selected coordinates and radius one by one
            feature.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y)).buffer(radius,100))

            #need to add something here to get the values from selected features and add the radius value to the Band field
            provider.addFeatures( [feature] )
            item+=item


    vpoly.commitChanges()         
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vpoly)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an attribute field and get its id with:

```
res = provider.addAttributes( [ QgsField("RADIUS", QVariant.Float) ] )
RADIUS_idx = vlayer.fieldNameIndex('RADIUS')
```

If, as you requested, want to set up all the attributes BEFORE you add the feature you need to know all the attributes in advance then create them with:

```
feature.setAttributes([attrib_id0_val,attrib_id1_val, attrib_id2_val ...])
```

However I think you might prefer to subsiquently alter some attributes after feature creation with:

```
fid=feature.id()
attrs = { RADIUS_idx : RADIUS_value}
provider.changeAttributeValues({ fid : attrs })
```