# QGIS script doesn't commit attribute changes

Tags: qgis, python, fields-attributes

I have a script to generate random points within a polygon, and to give the points the attributes of their host polygon. It generates points, but for some reason it won't commit the changes to the attributes. The weird thing is that the output while running the script clearly shows the feature it is adding has the attributes, but when it's done I'm left with a bunch of featureless points with only an ID.

I have a feeling it's something fundamental I'm missing in committing the attributes.

```
import random

# Prepare new temporary editable memory layer
pointLayer = iface.addVectorLayer("Point?crs="+source.crs().toWkt(), "random_points", "memory")

for f in source.getFeatures():
    # Create bounding box from polygon
    bounds = f.geometry().boundingBox()
    attributes = f.attributes()
    xmin = bounds.xMinimum()
    xmax = bounds.xMaximum()
    ymin = bounds.yMinimum()
    ymax = bounds.yMaximum()

    for i in range(['Number']):

        inBounds = False
        while not inBounds:
            # generate random point 'p' within feature bounds 
            xRandom = xmin + (random.random() * (xmax-xmin))
            yRandom = ymin + (random.random() * (ymax-ymin))
            p = QgsPoint(xRandom,yRandom)
            pGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(p)

            # check if new point is contained in poly
            # if within bounds, add attributes and exit loop
            if f.geometry().contains(pGeom):
                pointFeature = QgsFeature()
                pointFeature.setGeometry(pGeom)
                print('source atts: ')
                print(attributes)
                pointFeature.setAttributes(attributes)
                print('point atts: ')
                print(pointFeature.attributes())
                pointLayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([pointFeature])
                inBounds = True
```

Comment: I'm no expert but perhaps if you add `pointLayer.commitChanges()` then that might save the attributes?

Comment: @Joseph I have tried that with `pointLayer.startEditing()` too, committing at the end and in the last if statement, same result.

Comment: How about `pointLayer.startEditing()` `pointLayer.addFeature(...)` `pointLayer.commitChanges()`? (I.e. no `pointLayer.dataProvider()...` calls)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Using `pointLayer.addFeature()` results in no points being written at all, with or without the edit/commit code.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#add-features (especially `f = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())` ) It also helps sometimes to check the return values of startEditing, commitChanges, addFeature etc. calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, thanks to Mr Purple: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108379/55808. I think the problem was that the fields weren't initialised for the new layer first. As the code ran and didn't complain I assumed it was magically adding the fields/attributes as it went through each feature, but apparently not.

```
import random

# Prepare new temporary editable memory layer
pointLayer = iface.addVectorLayer("Point?crs="+source.crs().toWkt(), "random_points", "memory")

prov = pointLayer.dataProvider()

#Generate attributes for new layer
sourceAttribNames = source.dataProvider().fields()
oldattributeList = source.dataProvider().fields().toList()
newattributeList = []
for a in oldattributeList:
    # if field not found, add
    if pointLayer.fieldNameIndex(a.name())==-1:
        newattributeList.append(QgsField(a.name(),a.type()))
prov.addAttributes(newattributeList)
pointLayer.updateFields()

for f in source.getFeatures():
    # Create bounding box from polygon
    bounds = f.geometry().boundingBox()
    attributes = f.attributes()
    xmin = bounds.xMinimum()
    xmax = bounds.xMaximum()
    ymin = bounds.yMinimum()
    ymax = bounds.yMaximum()

    for i in range(f['Number']):

        inBounds = False
        while not inBounds:
            # generate random point 'p' within feature bounds 
            xRandom = xmin + (random.random() * (xmax-xmin))
            yRandom = ymin + (random.random() * (ymax-ymin))
            p = QgsPoint(xRandom,yRandom)
            pGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(p)

            # check if new point is contained in poly
            # if within bounds, create feature, add attributes and exit loop
            if f.geometry().contains(pGeom):
                pointFeature = QgsFeature(pointLayer.pendingFields())
                pointFeature.setGeometry(pGeom)
                pointFeature.setAttributes(attributes)
                print(pointFeature.attributes())
                prov.addFeatures([pointFeature])
                pointLayer.updateFields()
                inBounds = True
                break
```